# jQuery Add Id to System Generated Popup

Tags: jquery

I have a system generated pop-up that gets triggered by clicking a button. I want to add an id to it so that I can adjust the inline CSS, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
$('div.ui-dialog').on('load', function() {
    $('div.ui-dialog').attr('id' , 'reposition');
});
```

html:

```
<input type="image" name="w1001303$ibtnUpdate" id="w1001303_ibtnUpdate" 
src="/SiteData/SiteID1/ObjectImages/update-address-2.jpg" alt="Update" 
onclick=" launchBillToAddressManager('w1001303_pnlAddressManager', 
'w1001303_hdnAddressID',  'w1001303_tdAddress', 23361347, null, null,  null, 
null, 'w1001303_chkSetBillToSameAsShipTo', 0); return false;" style="border-
width:0px;" rs_id="1221">
```

Comment: Show your HTML also

Comment: Liza, was the answer helpful. Please respond

Comment: It did not work for me. I ended up changing my code completely.

Comment: ok no problem ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `id` on the `click` event of the `<button>`. Let's say the button id is `btn` then you can do this,

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    $('div.ui-dialog').attr('id', 'reposition');
});
```

Also, make sure you have `jquery` file included in the `HTML`.